# Reset iOS Simulator Content and Add Photos

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcrun, simctl

For UI Automation testing, I want to have a Reset iOS Simulator and then add a few photos to it before being my automation scripts begin.

When I run this:

> xcrun simctl erase device_UUID
>
> xcrun simctl addphoto device_UUID ~/Desktop/photos/photo1.PNG

I get this error:

> An error was encountered processing the command (code=146):
>
> Invalid device state

How can I erase the simulator and then add photos to it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

After erasing the simulator, you have to launch it first before the 'addphoto' command will work.

It doesn't work to launch it programmatically with the command `xcrun simctl boot`

So far this is the only thing I've gotten to work.

> xcrun simctl erase device_UUID
>
> open -a "iOS Simulator" --args -CurrentDeviceUDID device_UUID
>
> sleep 5
>
> xcrun simctl addphoto device_UUID ~/Desktop/photos/photo1.PNG
>
> sleep 1
>
> killall "iOS Simulator"

Since I loop through all of the simulators to set them all up with photos, I have to kill the simulator before opening the next one.

Answer (score 0):

The device must be booted in order to add photos to it.